# Payments bitcoin Error trying to send payments with RPC sendmany {"code":-5,"message":"Invalid BTC address: 9aK3cr3"}

Tags: bitcoin-core, rpc-error-5

someone could help me with this error:

[Payments] [bitcoin] Error trying to send payments with RPC sendmany {"code":-5,"message":"Invalid BTC address: 9aK3cr3"}

Since I have this error the pool has not paid the miners...

Thank you so much

Comment: 9aK3cr3 is not a valid Bitcoin address. What do you expect?

Comment: Thanks for answering. But how do I remove the record with the invalid wallet address (9aK3cr3); Therefore, while this error originates, the other payments are not executed

Comment: You'll need to explain what your code is doing, what packages you're using, what you expect to happen , ...

Comment: The application that I am using:

- nomp (pool mining)
- redis NoSQL
- Node.js v0.10.25
- npm 1.3.10

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information, as well as any excerpts from your code that may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your calling **`sendmany`** so you have to send bitcoin addresses/amount as object and don't forget to attach `fromaccount` parameter.

```
sendmany account '{"address":amount,"address":amount}'
```

or you can leave account parameter empty, but you have to call it.

```
sendmany "" '{"address":amount,"address":amount}'
```

also you can call `validateaddress` to check if address is valid or not.

```
bitcoin-cli validateaddress 'yourbitcoinAddress'
```

Please read more [here](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#sendmany).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

comment on this portion of the code, so that the error would pop up, and the pool kept working

else if (result.error) {
        logger.error(logSystem, logComponent, 'Error trying to send payments with RPC sendmany '
            + JSON.stringify(result.error));
            callback(true);
        }

Comment: Now the pending payments of some miners do not make them, it is only making the payments of the new transactions. Is there any way to force these payments?

Comment: ... sorry. the edited program was: paymentProcessor.js